# Ancient number formats (probably fixed-point)

Tags: binary-analysis, file-format

I'm analyzing an rather ancient 3D mesh format (from 1995 or 1996). Inside the files, there are blocks of what I think are vertices.

For example, the following is a direct hex dump from such a part:

```
7855DAFF
5BE60E00
353D0200
C82D0B00
5BE60E00
353D0200
C82D0B00
5BE60E00
B61AEDFF
7855DAFF
5BE60E00
B61AEDFF
7855DAFF
59D2FDFF
363D0200
C82D0B00
59D2FDFF
363D0200
C82D0B00
59D2FDFF
B61AEDFF
7855DAFF
59D2FDFF
B61AEDFF
```

These blocks are introduced by a little header, which has a value that could be the number of vertices that are present in the corresponding data block. For this excerpt, there is a `0x08`. Since we have 24 values of 32bit, I think it is safe to assume that these blocks are actual vertices (`0x08 * 3 = 24`, with `xyz`). Other headers also have this value and their data blocks also have the exact number of `dwords ([value in header] * 3 => number of dwords`).

But, now I'm struggling at deciphering the number format that was used. It isn't IEEE754; a friend of mine also pointed out that the hardware that was used these days didn't perform well with floating-point numbers and therefore often fixed-point numbers where used.

So, any idea what kind of format this could be ?

Comment: I wonder if the fact that every word ends with either FF or 00 has meaning? Or are you sure they are not simply 32-bit integers?

Comment: Do you know, or can you find out, which kind of hardware that was? Knowing which processor was used could help a lot, and even if you just know "it was some kind of bumblebee", there might be someone here who worked with bumblebees 20 years ago and remembers some details.

Comment: It was mainly designed for the 80486 (minimum requirements of 33 MHz), so I think it is safe to assume 32bit dwords.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you reverse the byte order, and assume signed numbers you get these triplets:

```
-2468488  976475   146741
  732616  976475   146741
  732616  976475 -1238346
-2468488  976475 -1238346
-2468488 -142759   146742
  732616 -142759   146742
  732616 -142759 -1238346
-2468488 -142759 -1238346
```

these seem like the coordinates of the corners of a 3d cube

```
x=(-2468488 .. 732616)
y=( -142759 .. 976475)
z=(-1238346 .. 146742)
```

Comment: Ah, it could be so simple. I'll try it with other, bigger sets of vertices and import them into Blender to see whats going on.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Just simple 32bit signed ints. I successfully managed to extract the vertices. Now I need to normalize them. I want the dimension with the largest extend to lie between 0 and 1 and the smaller dimensions to lie between 0 and <0. Aspect ratio should be maintained. Should I ask here or somewhere else? What's the right way?

Comment: You may want to state _why_ you reversed the byte order, because I was initially slightly confused as to that point.

Comment: The byte order has to be reversed because the numbers are saved in little endian format.

Comment: @madmartin: i think that is more a math question, what you are looking for is called translation, and scaling.